# How to chain multiple ItemReaders in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to use and chain multiple `ItemReader`s in `spring-batch`?

I have a large file that contains several XML records.
I now want to use the `FlatFileItemReader` to read the lines and `SeparationPolicy` to detect start and end of a xml record.

Then I'd like to use `StaxEventItemReader` to convert the xml to java classes.

So is it possible to chain both readers?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this by rolling your own ItemReader which is composed of the other two readers, but i'm not sure this will work with how the stax events are processed (I suspect not). Something like this:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/51940-composite-reader

Another suggestion you might want to consider is to convert this into two steps:

1. use the `FlatFileItemReader` to pre-process the file into proper XML and write it out to another file
2. Read in the XML file from step 1 using `StaxEvenItemReader`

The upshot of this approach is that if something goes wrong on the stax side, you still have the work from the flat file parsing saved in an intermediate file and you could retry with it.

Comment: The question then is: how can I feed `StaxEventItemReader` by multiple resources? Because it only has on for `setRecouces(res)`. I could then read the xml string proprocessed with `FlatFileItemReader`, write it to `ListItemWriter`, and pass these resources from `listItemWriter.getWrittenItems()` to the stax. But how?

Comment: @membersound To feed the `StaxEventItemReader` multiple resources, use a `MultiResourceItemReader` : https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html

Answer (score 2):

Do something like a [`JsonLineMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/JsonLineMapper.html)
Write a custom [`LineMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/LineMapper.html); inject a JAXB context and unmarshal line to create your domain object.